# Factory of inner class objects

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create an abstract class (A) that returns an instance of a generic child of itself (B).

I made B's costructor internal, making the creation of a new instance without my factory impossible, this caused an error I cannot seem to find a solution for:

> 'A.B' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method A.Create().

Is there a solution for such a problem in C#?

```
namespace C
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main() => Console.WriteLine(A.Create<A.B>().GetType());
    }
    public abstract class A
    {
        public class B : A { protected B() { } }
        public static T Create<T>() where T : A, new() => new T();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possible solution where the only accessible way to create an inner type of `A` is to use `Create<T>` with the inner type as the type argument, or by reflection on the `IFactory<T>` implementations.

```
public abstract class A
{
    private A() { }

    private static IDictionary<Type, IFactory> factories = new Dictionary<Type, IFactory>
    {
        {typeof(B), new B.BFactory() },
        {typeof(C), new C.CFactory() }
    };

    public static T Create<T>() where T : A 
        => factories.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var factory) ? ((IFactory<T>)factory).Create() : throw new InvalidOperationException();

    private interface IFactory { }
    private interface IFactory<T> : IFactory
    {
        T Create();
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        private B() { }

        public class BFactory : IFactory<B>
        {
            B IFactory<B>.Create() => new B();
        }
    }

    public class C : A
    {
        private C() { }

        public class CFactory : IFactory<C>
        {
            C IFactory<C>.Create() => new C();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is excatly what I was looking for! I could technicaly create an instance of `BFactory` but that is negligable as I can't use any of it's functions outside of class A anyways!

Answer (score 6):

`public static T Create<T>() where T : A, new()` defines a public method stating that `T` must have a public constructor because of the generic type constraint `new()`. Therefore the constructor cannot be protected or internal.

Move the static factory method `Create` to the class `B` instead.

```
class P
{
    static void Main() => Console.WriteLine(A.B.Create().GetType());
}

public abstract class A
{
    public class B : A
    {
        private B() { }
        public static B Create() => new B();
    }
}
```

A more generic approach is to use a dictionary of factory delegates allowing you to keep the constructors private.

```
class P
{
    static void Main() => Console.WriteLine(A.Create<A.B>().GetType());
}

public abstract class A
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<A>> _factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<A>> {
        [typeof(B)] = () => B.Create(), // Example using factory method.
        [typeof(C)] = () => new C()     // Example using constructor.
    };

    public static T Create<T>() where T : A => (T)_factories[typeof(T)]();

    public class B : A
    {
        private B() { }
        internal static B Create() => new B();
    }

    public class C : A
    {
        internal C() { }
    }
}
```

In a real world example you might want to add some error checking. If making the constructors `internal` is enough protection for you, you don't need the factory methods in the internal classes (shown with class `C`).

You could also expose interfaces instead and keep the classes (except some static factory class) completely private.

Consider also using a dependency injection container. Their aim is to solve this type of problem (and much more).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have thought about this solution, and the thing about it is you will have to write the create function for each class that inherits from A. Is there no option more generic than this? Ideally something like `public static T Create<T>() where T : A, protected new() => new T();`

Comment: `public static T Create<T>() where T : A => (T)_factories[typeof(T)]();` This line of code is a masterpiece. So glad to have seen it!

Answer (score 2):

This is your class:

```
public class B : A { protected B() { } }
```

The constructor is `protected`; therefore, only those classes that inherit `B` will be able to call the constructor. No one else.

**Another Approach**

Not sure if you like this but one approach you can take is to create a public abstract class and then make your concrete types private. The clients will only use the abstract interface but ask you to create a specific concrete type through a method. Something like below:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public abstract string DoSomething();
}

public abstract class A
{
    private class B : SomeClass
    {
        public override string DoSomething()
        {
            return "Something is done in B";
        }
    }
    public static SomeClass CreateB()
    {
        SomeClass sc = new B();
        return sc;
    }
}
public  static class Program
{
   public static void Main()
    {
        var b = A.CreateB();
        Console.WriteLine(b.DoSomething());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is there no option to write a class that can be created by only it's parent?

Comment: @RemotH See my edit please. This is all I can think of. No there is no way to restrict the construction from within a parent class only--at least I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up with approach very similar to [@Olivier Jacot-Descombes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47488735/1094048)'. The difference is only in that children of A are outside of it:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var ab = A.Create<B>();
        ab.Foo();

        var ac = A.Create<C>();
        ac.Foo();
    }
}

public abstract class A
{
    public virtual void Foo() => Console.WriteLine("A");

    public static A Create<T>()
        where T : A
    {
        return Factories[typeof(T)]();
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<A>> Factories;
    static A()
    {
        Factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<A>>();
        B.AppendFactory(Factories);
        C.AppendFactory(Factories);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    private B() => Console.WriteLine("B.ctor()");
    public override void Foo() => Console.WriteLine("B");

    public static void AppendFactory(Dictionary<Type, Func<A>> factories)
    {
        factories.TryAdd(typeof(B), () => new B());
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    private C() => Console.WriteLine("C.ctor()");
    public override void Foo() => Console.WriteLine("C");

    public static void AppendFactory(Dictionary<Type, Func<A>> factories)
    {
        factories.TryAdd(typeof(C), () => new C());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! The problem with your solution is that I am forced to create a method for each class I create, forcing me to rewrite practically the same code. I was looking for a more generic approach.

Comment: All your children private classes are inaccessible to the outer world - only the class A knows about them. So `clean` generic approach is just not implementable.

Comment: But you can always hack it, using some `enum` or `string` as parameter of your factory method, which tells what child exactly you wanna get. It just looks kinda wrong to me :)

Comment: @RemotH I've updated my answer and probably solved your problem.

Comment: Ah, no :( I don't like it. There're more than one points to create instances and too much boilerplate code. Sorry

Comment: I'ts not ideal but I enjoyed reading it and learned a lot from it so thanks!

Comment: @RemotH, you're welcome! At first glance the problem seemed stupid for me and ended up very interesting and non-obvious, haha! :)